# Combine Unitofwork along with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have implemented generic repository pattern along with unit of work in my project. There is only one method in unit of work to commit the changes in `dbcontext`. Also, I have used [code-first stored procedure](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/179481/Code-First-Stored-Procedures) library for accessing stored procedure.

My unit of work code looks like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly MyDataContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContext = new MyDataContext();
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

It is working as expected. But if I want to access stored procedure along with entity framework then it creates problem as the transaction for stored procedure and entity framework will be different.

`CodeFirstStoredProcedure` library supports `DbTransaction` and Entity Framework supports `DbContextTransaction` which provide `DbTransaction` property as

```
public DbTransaction UnderlyingTransaction { get; }
```

I want to make my `UnitOfWork` as transaction handler for both the cases. When object of unit of work is created then transaction for Entity Framework should begin and when that transaction object should be passed to stored procedure. So that both the frameworks share common transaction object.

I tried this code for it:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable, IDbTransaction
{
    private readonly MyDataContext _dbContext;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _dbContext = new MyDataContext();
    }

    public IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public IsolationLevel IsolationLevel
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Rollback()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int Save()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to pass `Dbtransaction` object to Entity Framework so that I can create new instance of `DbTransaction` for unit of work and store it as property to use in Entity Framework and stored procedures.